# Windows always starts again (= wakes up) from standby (= sleep) after some seconds in standby (with wireless devices like mouse or keyboard in use)

Tags: windows, sleep, wake-up, standby

On a Windows laptop (question is for pc as well), when I enter the standby mode, it automatically wakes up again after a few seconds.

I vaguely remember having solved this before. That is why I guess that this problem occured after a Windows update which has reset some needed changes in the settings.

The problem only pops up when I use wireless devices like mouse or keyboard.

How to avoid this, so that Windows is kept sleeping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Workaround

This can be fixed by changing the mouse driver properties.

All credits go to [How to Stop Your Mouse from Waking Up Your Windows PC](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15132/stop-your-mouse-from-waking-up-your-windows-7-computer/). There, the final screenshot shows it all:

[image]

Please follow the guide if you do not know how to find the HID-complient mouse properties.

*Of course, you should only switch off the mouse from being able to wake up your Windows when it is really causing the problem at hand. The average user will want to wake up Windows with a mouse move.*

The same accounts for a wireless extra keyboard. Then you need to uncheck the external keyboard from being able to wake the computer from sleep as well:

[image]

---

#### Guessing why

My first guess that this happens because of a laser search of the laser mouse (and / or the bad surface of the mousepad) was wrong since the same happened again when I had an external keyboard without touching anything of it. Therefore, it is probably the wireless signal that wakes up from standby, which means that you need to uncheck the wake option for any of such wireless devices.

Comment: Your mouse must have a problem, so replace it. Almost everybody would prefer his computer to wake up if the mouse is moved.

Comment: @harrymc I will not replace my beloved ergonomic laser mouse only for this. This will help all of the other people thinking the same. It might also just happen because I do not use a mouse pad, so that the laser might search a bit more for the right angle which slightly moves the cursor once in a while.

Comment: This should then be noted in the question or your answer, not presented as a general solution.

Comment: @harrymc Done. Only your comment brought up the idea. Thanks. I rather think that it is a problem of the mouse itself since I remember having used the mouse on a standard mouse pad with the same problem. And again, I would not replace it just because of this.

Comment: In my case (regular pc) the ethernet port was receiving traffic during hibernation/standby that caused it to wake up. In that case change the same setting on your network card via device manager.

Comment: @megamorf Would be nice if you added an answer.