# How to make it the default that a wireless device cannot wake up Windows from standby?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, wake-up, standby

When I plug-in a dongle of a wireless mouse or keyboard, often even if I just switch already known mice when I am underway, I often need to change the Windows settings of the "HID conform" device in the device manager to make it possible that the computer stays in standby when the device is plugged in.

This is explained and solved at [Windows always starts again (= wakes up) from standby (= sleep) after some seconds in standby (with wireless devices like mouse or keyboard in use)](https://superuser.com/questions/1649931/windows-always-starts-again-wakes-up-from-standby-sleep-after-some-secon).

I do not want to change it at any plugged in wireless device over and over again, often realising only after hours that the standby had not worked and the computer was running the whole time, at a closed screen.

This is the current default which makes standby impossible:

[image]

The example shows the "HID conform mouse" with this issue, but you have the same issue with a keyboard.

Is there a way on Windows to make it the default option that the checkbox "Device can activate the computer from standby." is unchecked?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either disable the mouse in Device Manager (not very helpful really) or turn off the mouse (switch on the mouse). I have had to do that.

Bluetooth mice are better and if the mouse is not really close to the laptop, the mouse will not turn it on.

I use a LogiTech Bluetooth mouse to minimize this issue. Also, even after I suspend the laptop, I can still turn the Bluetooth mouse off. I do this before packing my bag with the laptop and mouse.

If your mouse has the little wireless USB device in the laptop, simply remove that before you suspend. Sometimes this will work after the laptop is suspended.

I have seen this issue of some mice turning on suspended laptops for many years.

Comment: What an easy and working idea, I did not get it at first that it would be *that* easy to be solved, after struggling with this for so long! As you write it, just switching off the mouse / keyboard or whatever device causing the error helps. If you then go into standby mode, the device does not wake up unless it is switched on again.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections and I did that